# SAP Business One Integration Framework browser stuck on "Loading"

Tags: sap-business-one-di-api

I spun up an instance of Business One using the SAP Cloud Appliance Library that included an install of the Integration Framework but when I try to load the framework via the browser (127.0.0.1:8080/) I get stuck on a "Loading" screen. I've turned off IE Enhanced Security Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Add the site to your Trusted Site list in IE.